# mysql query Callback return value to a variable

Tags: mysql, node.js

I am trying to accomplish a simple goal, i am querying mysql (input from HTML get message) and want to display the results in a HTML table format.

So first step in the process is to capture results from mysql query into a variable.

I have declared a variable in Global Scope, and assigning results from callback to variable.

But somehow results doesnt work outside the localscope.

```
var newResults;

var custquery = 'SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cust_name = ?';

var usercon = mysql.createConnection ({
  host    : 'localhost' ,
  user    : 'root'  ,
  password  : ''  ,
  database  : 'test' ,
  table   : 'customer'
 });

app.get('/search',function(request,response){
  var customerName = request.query.key;
  usercon.query(custquery,customerName,function(err,results,fields){
   newResults = results;
    });
}); 


console.log(newResults);
```

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The variable newResults does not get set until you GET /search/ , by this time the console.log has already happened.

Move the log inside the app.get

```
app.get('/search',function(request,response){
  var customerName = request.query.key;
  usercon.query(custquery,customerName,function(err,results,fields){
  newResults = results;
   });
 console.log(newResults);
});
```